# YouTube Monthly views checker API and PHP?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels

My question is if there's a way to get the monthly original views. From a YouTube channel with Google Authentication system and YouTube APIs. Because i'm writing a little script that say's like when a curtain person get over a amount of, monthly views they will get sended further in to the site and get a document send through. Else they go back to the homepage, Is it possible to do this so yes how because i can't seem to find a way

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/) to run a report against a given video to request the number of "[uniques](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#uniques)" aggregated by month, for an arbitrary date range. The report definition would look something like

```
ids=channel==UC...
dimensions=month
metrics=uniques
filters=video==VIDEO_ID
start-date=2013-01-01
end-date=2013-01-01
```

You'd have to run that report once against every video in the channel, though, and add up the totals.

Note that the end-date is NOT the last day of the month you're looking for, it's the first day of that month again (i.e. it's a "month identifier", not a range of days).

You should note that you need to have an OAuth 2 token for the owner of the channel with the appropriate YouTube Analytics (and Data API, to get the list of videos) scopes in order to run that report; you can't just run an arbitrary Analytics report for an arbitrary video without being authorized.

Comment: That's exactly the request I'm trying to do, but all I get is a "Date range (2013-01-31) in field parameters.end-date does not align to chosen date dimension."

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I'll just update your answer to fix our common mistake ;)